# How can i use php variable from js?

Tags: php, jquery, local-storage

I have several products. On click product, I send "id" of clicked product to Local Storage. To use this variable in php I send it to items.php ($.post).

Then I need use this "id" from items.php to show in the cart, but variable is emply.

```
var LSArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productID')) || [];

function clickOnProduct(id) {
    var newItem = {'id': id};
    LSArray.push(newItem);

    localStorage.setItem("productID", JSON.stringify(LSArray));
    var dataLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productID')) ;

    $.ajax({
                type : "POST", 
                url  : "/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/items.php", 
                data : { name : dataLS[dataLS.length-1].id },
                success: function(res){  
                    console.log(res);
                }
        });
}
```

All works fine, but how can I use "id"?

```
<?php incude(items.php); ?>
```

dosn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code for items.php? Otherwise it is not clear how you are handling the POST.

Comment: <?php 
echo $name = $_POST['name'];
?>   I want to use $name on other pages, but it is empty :(

Comment: @ТатьянаКомпаниец No. Just `<?echo $_POST['name'];?>` to print it. Or if you want to assign its value to another variable, then `<?php $name=$_POST['name'] ;?>` But by doing that make no real sense.

Comment: Why no sense? How to do correctly? I write <?php $name=$_POST['name'] ;?> and in another page <?php include('items.php');  echo $name; ?>, but doesn't work:(

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. So it runs at the time of the function call, but when you visit the other page, you're running your PHP code without the POST. It's a timing issue.

Comment: Then how can I get data from Local Storage and use it?

Comment: in items.php, store the incoming POST in a SESSION variable. Then you can go to the other page, and access the values from the session instead of including items.php

Answer (score -1):

You are sending it by post. So you can take a look to your post variable by

`<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>`

Then you will see the array and probably you can access your data by
`$_POST['name']`

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: array(0) { }  :(